Troubleshooting Routing Problem in Laravel 10
I'm having a problem with Routes.
On web.php, I set Routes but it doesn't appear on Blade.php.
Technically it appears but I haven't seen this format before.
I don't know how to fix this issue.
Could somebody fix it ?
web.php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'seller', 'as' => 'seller.'], function () {
    Route::get('/signIn', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SellerLoginController::class, 'showLoginPage']);

    Route::post('signIn', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SellerLoginController::class, 'signIn'])->name('seller.signin');
}



i am not sure why you are not using route name i.e. route('seller/signIn') ?

It's something related to the IDE (PhpStorm).

Clear route cache and then try.
php artisan route:clear


You should use the Laravel recommended methods for prefix and name, so its easier. So your Route group should look like
Route::prefix('/seller')->name('seller.')->group(function () {
    Route::post('signIn', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SellerLoginController::class, 'signIn'])->name('signin');
}

And then it should popup in the blade as seller.signin

Thank you dz0nika.
But it doesn't still work.
